# PDFView does not display my PDF

Tags: swift, pdf

I am having trouble getting my pdfView to display a PDF from a URL. I can get the file, and it definitely exists according to the console.  Here's what I've done:

First, I declare a document picker:

```
 @IBAction func addFromICloud(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.composite-content"], in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.formSheet
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Second, I get a URL and the name of the document from DocumentPickerViewController:

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController,
                    didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    print ("Picker's url is \(url)")
    theName = String(describing:url.lastPathComponent)
    books.append(theName)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then, I append theName to the document directory path:

```
fileIsFromService = true
indexPoint = indexPath.row
let DocumentDirectory = try! FileManager.default.url(for:  .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
docURL = DocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(theName)
```

Then I make sure that the file exists, and it does:

```
let fileExists = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: (finalDocURL?.path)!)
print ("The value of fileExists is \(fileExists)")
addressArray.append(docURL!)
print ("The url to be passed should be \(docURL!)")
print ("addressArray is now \(addressArray)")
indexPoint = indexPath.row
viewController.load(books[indexPath.row])
```

Then, in viewController, I try to load the pdfView with docURL:

```
func load(_ name: String) {
    if fileIsFromService == true {
        guard let path = docURL else {return}

        if let document = PDFDocument(url: path){
            pdfView.document = document
        }

        pdfView.goToFirstPage(nil)

        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            title = name
        }
    }
```

I get no errors, just a blank pdfView. I know that the pdfView's subview has been added. No variables are nil. I suspect that I need to get the data out of docURL, but where would I write it?

Comment: What mode was used for the document picker? Import or open?

Comment: Neither one. Where does that parameter get added?

Comment: On the line where you create the instance of the document picker (which isn't posted in your question).

Comment: Yes, for some reason the pickerview displayed even though my IBAction was incomplete:

Comment: Huh? I don't understand you last comment. Again, what mode did you use when you created your `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that I set the mode to .import.  (The pdfView is still blank, though.) .open didn't work at all, it prevented my tableview from updating.  I edited my question and added the picker declaration.

Comment: Now I have an error in the console that gives me a clue:  [DocumentManager] The view service did terminate with error: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}  ----- So something is nil, I assume, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @user3140521 you need to copy your pdf to your app documents folder. **UIDocumentPickerModeImport
The URLs refer to a copy of the selected documents. These documents are temporary files. They remain available only until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, move these files to a permanent location inside your sandbox.**

Comment: So I should get the Data from the contents of the URL and write them to the document directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the pdf you are importing it is just a temporary file. You need to copy/move the temporary file url to your app documents folder.

> UIDocumentPickerModeImport The URL refers to a copy of the selected
>   document. This document is a temporary file. It remains available only
>   until your application terminates. To keep a permanent copy, you must
>   move this file to a permanent location inside your sandbox.

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url.standardizedFileURL, to: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent))
        tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but OP probably wants to use .copyItem instead of .moveItem @LeoDabus

Comment: @aritroper this doesn't make any difference considering the file location is temporary,. It will be deleted anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't .moveItem actually move the original file to the temporary location? I'm guessing OP doesn't want to displace the original file @LeoDabus

Comment: The "original" file is already a copy at a temporary location

Comment: Ah, I see. makes sense. :)

Comment: It sounds like it's not possible to move a file (or delete a file) in the original location outside the sandbox. I assume this is intentional behavior--maybe so your app can't disturb the state of things outside itself?

Comment: As you can see it says it is a "copy" of the document. It is inside your app bundle but it is a temporary file. You are supposed to copy the file before trying to change it.

Comment: Note that OP is using the `import` option and that initializer is deprecated. You need to use the new `convenience init(forOpeningContentTypes contentTypes: [UTType])` if you would like to edit the original file. If you need to import/copy the file you need to use `init(forOpeningContentTypes contentTypes: [UTType], asCopy: Bool)`