# Uploading files from iOS Files app in another app

Tags: swift, ios11, eureka-forms

I'm looking to add functionality to my app that would allow a user to upload a file within my app from the Files app that was introduced in iOS 11. I would expect that it would work the same way that existing components do now where you can select Upload a Photo or Video on your iOS device and it allows you to select items from within the Photos app. I have been searching and I have not been able to figure out a way to do this. I know Apple's Mail app has this functionality (under "Add Attachment"), but I have not found a way to surface this functionality in my own app.

Since I am using Eureka for my other row inputs, it would be ideal to have this in an Eureka component but right now I am just trying to figure out if it is even possible to select files from the Files app from another app with Apple's existing APIs.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to "download a file to your app from the Files app"?

Comment: No, I don't mean "download a file to your app from the Files app." My app connects to a REST service and I want to upload the file selected in the Files app to the REST service.

Comment: Then you must let the user select a file from the Files app which will download it to your app. From there you can upload to the REST service. `UIDocumentPickerViewController` is the solution.

Comment: @KateM https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133840/pdfview-does-not-display-my-pdf/48134186#48134186

Answer (score 1):

The Framework you are looking for is built in to `UIKit` in a class called [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller)

Comment: Your original answer of `UIDocumentPickerViewController` is probably more correct than using `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`.