# Can I get the actual location of an iOS file from a Document Picker?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I can't get UIDocumentPickerMode.*open* to work.

UIDocumentPickerMode.*import* works, but the resulting url is for the temporary file (for the simulator)
    "file:///Users/*name*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*identifier*/data/Containers/Data/Application/*identifier*/**tmp**/***myApp***/filename" rather than "file:///Users/*name*/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*identifier*/data/Containers/Data/Application/*identifier*/**Documents**/***myAppDirectory***/filename"

I have no way of knowing if the file is **really** in a subdirectory or some other app's directory that I have access to.

If I can't use a document picker for this purpose, what should I be using?

If I should be working with the temporary file, I haven't found a working example for startAccessingSecurityScopedResource in Swift 4.

Addendum-
This is the code I tried:

```
    public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import {
            // This gives me a path to the temporary file
            let filePath = url.path
        }
        if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.open)
        {
            // this returns with nil for url
            let isAccessable:Bool =  url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            if(!isAccessable)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                let filePath = url.path
            }
            // Do work inside

            url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        }
    }

    // elsewhere in the code
    // open a document picker, select a file
    // let importFileMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
    let importFileMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.open)
    importFileMenu.delegate = self
    importFileMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(importFileMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use the import mode and copy the file to your app sandbox folder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48134186/2303865

Comment: Note the url is deprecated. you need to use urls method and if it is only a single url use the first property from the array.

Comment: But what if the file I want is already in my sandbox folder from a previous time using the app?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. Mode open opens the URL in place, so you’ll get the original URL inside the other app’s (or inside the cloud service) folder. You have to use startAccessing to access it. Mode import will copy the file to your inbox, and from there you can move it anywhere you want. It should not stay in your inbox.

Comment: I added the code that doesn't work for me with comments.